# Adding a filed to all of tables and procedures without edit them one by one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have more than 100 tables in the database and there are more than 500 store procedures use them, is it posible that I add a column to all tables and use in all procedures? Means not need to edit them one by one!
For example adding a filed with name **company** and two of procedures that I expected:

```
select * from Reseller
```

change to

```
select * from Reseller where company='DefaultValue'
```

Or

```
Insert into Reseller values(@name,@phone)
```

change to

```
Insert into Reseller values(@name,@phone,'DefaultValue')
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a column to *every* table. That sounds like a [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: I have two database for two different branch (reseller) with same structure and tables and procedures but data is different, I want to merge them and each of reseller see its data!

Comment: There's no magic light-switch for changing insert statements in all your stored procedures to suddenly reference a new column (and if you're really just saying `Insert into Reseller values`, now is an opportunity to fix that awful habit and name your columns explicitly, and maybe put your stuff into source control so vast, sweeping changes can be rolled out together instead of sequentially in a query window).

Comment: So `select * from Reseller where ShoeWidth = 'E' or Color = 'FF0000';` would become `select * from Reseller where ( ShoeWidth = 'E' or Color = 'FF0000' ) and Company = 'DefaultValue';` since the parentheses are obviously needed to control the operator precedence?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a great idea to update all fields in your database with one query, as it is too easy to provide incorrect ranges and update tables that perhaps don't need it.

On the few occasions I've needed to update several tables at once I query a list of all table names in the database I need and append the update TSQL logic to it either in the query or using excel so I can view it row by row.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', Table_Name, ' ADD Company NVARCHAR(50);' )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Then, I can copy the results and run results of the select statement as a new TSQL update.

With that said, I would absolutely not alter a stored procedure using this method. It would be far too easy to overwrite the existing content and lose the logic that the stored procedure utilizes

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to rename `Reseller` to `ResellerWithCompany`, then create a view `Reseller` that selects from it.

```
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.Reseller', N'ResellerWithCompany', 'OBJECT';

ALTER TABLE dbo.ResellerWithCompany
  ADD Company varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default value';

GO
```

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Reseller
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ResellerWithCompany
WHERE Company = 'default value';

GO
```

Given that this view is very simple, it can be inserted into, updated, and deleted from. On an `INSERT`, as long as all columns are specified or have a default value, it will just work.

There are some things that will not work.

- `TRUNCATE`
- Any kind of DDL, such as adding columns or constraints, rebuilding indexes, must be done on the base table

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=339ce719c56945c59c1645cb05b1b2be)